# Wordpress text widget with onclick function

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have a text widget, in it i just place there an iframe.

A few days ago i wanted to override this widget on mobile browsers and add a background of an image on mobile browsers, luckily i used [How to hide widget on mobile](https://woorkup.com/hide-wordpress-widgets-mobile-devices/) , i changed the code from that link instead of hiding the widget on mobile i simply give it a background image.

Now my questions is how can i add an onclick function to this widget, for example when this widget is clicked on a mobile browser i call a shortcode.

Any code examples of how to add some javascript to a text widget so that when it is clicked i call a shortcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally all i had to do is specify the mobile custom css code, i give it a name then make it only visible to mobile (800width and above are not mobile, probably tablet, pc e.t.c)

```
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 800px) {

.media{ display: none; }

}


@media only screen 
and (min-width : 800px) {


.vid{
    display: none;
}   

}
```

Then from my widget i add the image background pointing to a custom function i put in the header.php

```
<img class="vid" onclick="myFunction();" src="http://www.domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/button.png"  />
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is not related to javascript. But maybe this can help.

Check out the conditional tag wp_is_mobile

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_is_mobile

```
if ( wp_is_mobile() ) { 
  echo do_shortcode('[YOUR-CUSTOM-MOBILE-SHORTCODE]');
} else {
  echo do_shortcode('[YOUR-CUSTOM-DESKTOP-SHORTCODE]');
}
```

You should be able to display whatever you want on mobile and then something different on desktop.